# How can I use ng-if in a button to show the rest of a form in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have this button : `<button type = "button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" > Données du cheque</button>`
by clicking it I want the rest of my form to show up, I think that I should use a boolean or something like that ! how can I do this using Ng-if ? here is the code of the rest of the form that I want to show by clicking on the button:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <strong>Données du Chèque </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="numCheque-input"> Numéro du Chèque : </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="numCheque" id="numCheque-input" name="numCheque-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero du Chèque">
               
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="emisLe-input">Emis le: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="date" id="emisLe-input" name="emisLe-input" class="form-control" placeholder="date d'emission">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="montant-input">Montant : </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="montant-input" name="montant-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Montant">
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label">Ne sera pas honoré pour: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="option1"> Absence de provision 
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" value="option2"> Isuffisance de provision
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox3">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" value="option3"> Compte cloturé
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox4">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox4" value="option4"> Signature non conforme
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        


             <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label">Situation: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <div class="radio">
                  <label for="radio1">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="option1"> Au plus tard le: 
                    <input type="date" id="val1" name="val1" class="form-control" >
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label for="radio2">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="option2"> Avant le: 
                    <input type="date" id="val2" name="val2" class="form-control" >
                  </label>
                </div>
            
              </div>
            </div>
         
      
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
         
         <a [routerLink]="['/operateur/rejet-cheque']">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Annuler</button> 
          </a>  
          </form>
           </div> 
   
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-if works on boolean, so try to define a boolean flag in component and then use it in ng-if.

Ajouter

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <strong>Données du Chèque </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="numCheque-input"> Numéro du Chèque : </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="numCheque" id="numCheque-input" name="numCheque-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero du Chèque">
               
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="emisLe-input">Emis le: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="date" id="emisLe-input" name="emisLe-input" class="form-control" placeholder="date d'emission">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label" for="montant-input">Montant : </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="montant-input" name="montant-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Montant">
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label">Ne sera pas honoré pour: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="option1"> Absence de provision 
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" value="option2"> Isuffisance de provision
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox3">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" value="option3"> Compte cloturé
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox4">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="checkbox4" value="option4"> Signature non conforme
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        


             <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-5 form-control-label">Situation: </label>
              <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <div class="radio">
                  <label for="radio1">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="option1"> Au plus tard le: 
                    <input type="date" id="val1" name="val1" class="form-control" >
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label for="radio2">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="option2"> Avant le: 
                    <input type="date" id="val2" name="val2" class="form-control" >
                  </label>
                </div>
            
              </div>
            </div>
         
      
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="flag">Ajouter</button>
         
         <a [routerLink]="['/operateur/rejet-cheque']">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Annuler</button> 
          </a>  
          </form>
           </div> 
   
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same, with the correction that it's `*ngIf="flag"` in Angular (not AngularJS... This naming convention is going to be a big problem, I can already tell)

Comment: in that case you can use *ngIf in place of ng-if